# MongoDate performance compared to Unix Timestamp for sorting

Tags: mongodb

We have an application that we keep documents with their creation time, however this time value will be used **only for sorting** and will not be used for displaying creation time.
I intuitively assume, storing creation time as unix timestamp in `Number` data type would perform better than storing it in `MongoDate` data type.

Is my assumption correct? Are there any advantages of using `MongoDate` data type considering my use case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB's ISODate() vs. UNIX Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332975/mongodbs-isodate-vs-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Mongodate value is stored it's as an 8 byte integer number ([reference](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)). The Unix time stamp is often stored as an 8 byte number as well.

The biggest advantage of a MongoDate is that there are operators that can work with the values in a natural way when used with the aggregation framework ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)).

Sorting will perform the same either way, as it's just a numerical comparison in both cases.