# Unix_Timestamp to mongo

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

there is a mysql query as follow,

```
SELECT Unix_Timestamp(last_executed)
    FROM mpres_seq
```

now i need to do same thing in php with MongoDB. In mongodb i have saved last_executed as ISO Date. How can i do that?
if i used
 `$collection = $global["dbmongo"] -> mpres_seq;
        $res = $collection->find(),array("last_executed"=>1,"_id"=>0));`

Is it work for me. I want to get last_executed, in same type and same pattern in mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB's ISODate() vs. UNIX Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332975/mongodbs-isodate-vs-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply print out the `sec`s of the `MongoDate`:

```
foreach($res as $row){
    echo $doc['last_executed']->sec;
}
```

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php